# Code is not compiling while trying to use typeid

Tags: c++, c++11, typeid

The following program failed to compile :

```
 #include <iostream>

 int main()
 {
   short x(3);
   int y (8);
   std::cout << typeid (x + y).name ();
   return 0;
  }
```

I am using Code::Blocks. Did I missed something?

Comment: You need to include `typeinfo`

Comment: From your profile: _"Damn sure, stack exchange will help me doing that."_ No, spending ten seconds reading the documentation will help you do that. We are not here to teach you obvious things for free on our own time.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit A webpage that only contains a photo of a beautiful girl (I can find more in google "FOR FREE") and a donate button. Wow, are you really looking for donation for that kind of thing. Who made this site haa? Remember...nobody is perfect. Not even you. Respect the beginners.

Comment: @DevashishJaiswal: It is not your status as a beginner that prevents me from having respect for you. It is the fact that you did not bother to look up the documentation, you speak to Rakeb in teenage "text speak" runes, and you disrespect _us_ by expecting us to do all the work for you. That plus comments like the one you just made. Your generation is sickeningly lazy and sickeningly entitled and I've about had enough of it.

Comment: And my profile, along with my avatar and a donate button, contains evidence of millions and millions of people helped over thousands of answers. I'm sorry if that is not good enough for you, sir. BTW your site which was allegedly "going good" has been suspended by your web host

Comment: Ohhh really...??? Give me some time please.

Comment: Atleast I m not asking for donation "FOR SERVING NOTHING", sir.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit I respect you but no one can bear this type of comments. I am sorry.

Comment: @DevashishJaiswal: I am not asking for donation "for serving nothing". I have not asked you for anything, but to do a little research before asking us to give you our time for free. Is that really so bad? Gees.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit Sorry....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Typeid operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid):

> The header `<typeinfo>` must be included before using `typeid` (if the header is not included, every use of the keyword typeid makes the program ill-formed.)

So include `typeinfo` first.

```
#include <typeinfo>
```

Comment: "U r ri8" are you serious? Couldn't be bothered to read the documentation, now can't be bothered to write "right" out in full? Gods, the laziness, it burns.....